# C: why are extra semicolons OK?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = -1, b = -10, c = 5;
    if (a > b)
        printf("Hello World");
    else
        printf("Get out World");;;;;;
}
```

Can anybody tell me why line number 8 still works, with multiple semicolons?

Comment: Because `-1` is greater than `-10`?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "still works"?

Comment: I mean that there are more than one semi-colon.

Comment: What is the actual output? What is your expected output. Which is line 8?

Comment: It's somewhat dangerous to omit curly brackets in control statements. Especially for someone who uses Python from time to time.

Comment: Its worse to abuse on semicolons :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An *empty statement* is legal in C. Since `;` is the *statement terminator*, multiple `;` are syntactically valid. Sometimes this is even useful: such as the `for (;;) {/*code here*/}` idiom.

(Although some compilers will warn you in appropriate instances).

Do note that, conceptually at least, the excess `;` in that line are **not** part of the `if` block.

Comment: A Sun Solaris compiler I once used emitted an **error** on this (which was *extremely* annoying). But that was a C++ compiler in the late 1990s. The 128bit `long double` more than made up for it though ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Your program just has a sequence of empty statements at the end of the `main` function.  It is parsed as this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = -1, b = -10, c = 5;

    if (a > b)
        printf("Hello World");
    else
        printf("Get out World");
    ;
    ;
    ;
    ;
    ;
}
```

Note that `int main()` should be written `int main(void)` and it should return an `int` value, for example `0`.  C99 makes this `return 0;` implicit, but it is considered bad style and it is indeed less portable to omit it.

Comment: `int main(void)` is a mistake... please correct your answer. The current way would be to either omit the `main` function's arguments (`int main()`) or put them in `int main(int argc, const char ** argv)}`), but **not** to put in the **wrong** argument (`int main(void)`...

Comment: @Myst: I'm afraid you are mistaken: your remark is correct for C++, but  not for C as the question is tagged.  **5.1.2.2.1 Program startup** The function called at program startup is named `main`. The implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of `int` and with no parameters: `int main(void) { /* ... */ }`
or with two parameters (referred to here as `argc` and `argv`, though any names may be used, ...): `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }` or equivalent; or in some other implementation-defined manner.

Comment: OMG, @chqrlie , I never saw that. Thanks. I apologize for my misinformed remark.

Comment: Not, `int main()` can be perfectly written as such, meaning an *undeterminate list of parameters* for the compiler, against `int main(void)` that means a *perfectly determinate **and empty** list of parameters* which is completely wrong.  What is that **5.1.2.2.1 ...** thing that you quote without reference?  Did you live in the times where main was declared as: `int main(argc, argv) char **argv; {...` ???  and that's perfectly valid C code.

Comment: @LuisColorado: I am just quoting the C11 Standard.  Similar language can be found in earlier versions of the standard. `int main() { ... }` will certainly compile and run smoothly, but the standard recommends otherwise.  I did indeed live through the 80s programming in C, and I do regret the slowness of the C standard committee to clean up some of the dark corners of the language.  It takes time and hard work to gain more than *some experience with C*... A humbling experience for sure.

Comment: @chqrlie, you are appealing the `C11 standard` as if it were the **unique** reference of the C programming language.  `K&R C` is also C, `pre-ansi` is also valid C code, and none of them complaint about that (and it is not even related to the question subject).  Don't be so pedantic, and allow for flexibility in what you accept and be strict only in what you emit.  The question was marked `C` and not `C11`, so your point is completely off-topic.  A perfectly valid definition for main is `main () { ... }` (without even putting the return type)

Comment: @LuisColorado: much of K&R C code does not compile anymore, or invokes undefined behavior. Compilers have become too smart. I just hinted with a *should*.

Comment: Tell me some C code not compiling for example, in GCC or Clang, and probably you have configured wrong options as default.  I'm afraid you are wrong.  I'm continously making tests about that precise statement and have not found `K&R` code that does not compile or behaves incorrectly (not being incorrect code)  But if you want to continue this thread, please take it off this question (continue by chat or email)

Comment: @chqrlie , I apologize for starting the discussion. It seems to me it's growing out of proportion... I'm not so sure debating the point is productive, no matter where the truth lies (and I meant "lies", not just "lays").

Comment: @Myst: never mind!  I shall continue this discussion with Luis when I return to civilisation.  Language lawyering seem harsh, but provides for interesting encounters (or the forth kind ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Extra semicolons in general are not "OK".

For example, changing your code slightly:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = -1, b = -10, c = 5;
    if (a > b)
        printf("Hello World");;;;;;
    else
        printf("Get out World");
}
```

That won't even compile.

Another example, and this one does compile:

```
   ...

   int done = 0;

   ...

   while ( !done );
   {
       ...

       done = 1;
   }

   ...
```

Comment: Please, illustrate people about why those examples don't compile, as the one who knows why doesn't even need the example, and the one who needs the example needs also to know the reasons.

Answer (score 2):

`;;;;;` are empty statements. They are allowed in C.

Comment: Are there any case like that?

Comment: I don't get your question.

Comment: empty statement are accepted anywhere a statement is accepted

Answer (score 2):

It's a *null statement* which you have after the printf() statment. Having more than one semi-colons is allowed.

*C11, §6.8.3, 4*

> A null statement (consisting of just a semicolon) performs no
>   operations

Answer (score 2):

Well, the `;` semicolon in C is a statement terminator, which means that you cannot put it where you like, **only at the end of a statement**.

The null statement (one that does nothing) is valid in C, which allow you to write things as the one you post, and things like:

```
while((data = do_read(...)) != NULL); /* skip input until EOF */
```

that should be more visible written as (a single semicolon is too small to be skipped in a quick read):

```
while((data = do_read(...)) != NULL) continue;
```

which looks better as you'll never think that the next line is inside the loop.

By the way, if you write something like:

```
if (a > b); /* <====== LOOK at this semicolon */
    printf("Hello World");;;;;;
else
    printf("Get out World");
```

it will not compile, as that means *if a greater than b just do nothing* and that's a good valid sentence in C.  By contrast you'll get an error several lines later, when the compiler gets to the `else` token and cannot match it to an `if` statement (remember, when you used the `;`, you finished the `if`statement)

That also happens to occur with the group of semicolons you put after the `printf("Hello World");` statement (the first semicolon terminates it, and also as the next token is not an `else` but a `;`, also terminates the `if` statement).

The statements in the example above are:

```
if (a > b); /* if a greater than b do nothing */
; /* do nothing */
; /* ... */
; /* ... */
; /* ... */
; /* do nothing */
else /* ERROR, else cannot begin a statement */
....
```

Here, as you got a syntax error from the compiler, you cannot have a good C program so you'll not get further analysing (the compiler tries to recover and continue parsing past that point, but you can have new errors originating of the new condition, or *fake errors*)

Answer (score 0):

As we know, semicolon (`;`) works as a statement terminator. In the Line no.8 the first semicolon terminates the statement under `else` and the next semicolon terminates the empty statement, and so on.