# why does semicolon in c++ does not show any error when inserted at the begining of code?

Tags: c++

I am a newbie in C++.

A semicolon is a terminator, so when it is included at the beginning of code it must terminate the line, i.e it should skip the line and start executing the next line. When I include a semicolon at the beginning of code, it does not show any error and the line is not terminated.

Please correct me.

Example:

```cpp
; string a = "5.558";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C: why are extra semicolons OK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38870692/c-why-are-extra-semicolons-ok)

Comment: It's not a terminator ... It's a separator.

Comment: Hm... Albeit the actual answer is the same as in the 'duplicate', we are in two different languages. So is this really a duplicate?

Comment: @Aconcagua i'd say no, unless the other quesiton is retagged as c++ also. However, usually the asker cannot know if the answer is the same in two different languages, so I wouldnt do that, not sure what is the accepted policy though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't get an error because it isn't one.
You are terminating an empty statement. That's legal in C++ (and has been in C).

So you're example consists of 2 statements (not one):

```
<empty> ;
string a = "5.558" ;
```

This can actually be useful. For instance, the `for` loop needs 3 expressions (init, condidtion and increment/step). Sometimes you don't want to pass all 3, so this is a legal code as well:

```
for(;;) {  /* do something in this endless loop */ }
```

The 2 semicolons inside for are therefore separators for 3 (empty) expressions

Answer (score 3):

There is no notion of "lines" in the c++ language. If you like you can put all your code on a single line (not recommended). If you write

```
int main() {
    ;     // <--
}
```

Then in the line marked with the comment you have an empty statement that does nothing. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479946/whats-an-expression-and-expression-statement-in-c). The quesiton is about statements vs expressions, but it might also help to better understand your issue.